# Getting warning message about tokenizer version when upgrading solr from 5.2 to 8.2

Tags: solr

I am upgrading Solr from version 5.2 to version 8.2

In the analyzers in my schema.xml file, I have the following references to tokenizer:

```
<tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
<tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
<tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
<tokenizer class="solr.PathHierarchyTokenizerFactory" delimiter="/" />
<tokenizer class="solr.JapaneseTokenizerFactory" mode="search"/>
<tokenizer class="solr.ThaiTokenizerFactory"/>
<tokenizer class="solr.HMMChineseTokenizerFactory"/>
```

When reolading the core on the 8.2 Solr server, I get the following warning:

```
TokenFilterFactory is using deprecated 4.10.2 emulation. You should at some point declare and reindex to at least 7.0,&#8203; because 6.x emulation is deprecated and will be removed in 8.0
```

What do I need to change to eliminate this warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have [to set the `luceneMatchVersion` in your `solrconfig.xml`, clear out the index and reindex your content](https://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Solr-6-1-Logging-WARN-FieldTypePluginLoader-tp4292207p4292233.html).

From Shawn Heisey's post linked above:

> The "luceneMatchVersion" setting in your solrconfig.xml file is 5.2.1.
>   It might also appear in schema.xml, but solrconfig.xml is more likely.
>
> The message is saying "right now, the config settings you're using
>   will be honored, but they won't be in the future."  This message is a
>   warning and will not cause Solr to blow up, even in 7.0.
>
> The first thing you'll need to do is change luceneMatchVersion to
>   match your Solr version -- 6.1.0 -- and reindex.
>
> https://wiki.apache.org/solr/HowToReindex
>
> Note that this may change how your analyzer chains defined in
>   schema.xml work.  The change may be obvious, it may be subtle, and in
>   some cases it might actually make no change at all.  I don't have a
>   list of changes that are made by different luceneMatchVersion
>   settings.
>
> One thing that luceneMatchVersion will *not* change is index format. 
>   I mention this because this is a common misconception.  The index
>   format will be decided by the version of Solr (Lucene) that you're
>   running, not luceneMatchVersion.

Comment: Thanx.  I set it to 8.2.0
However, I get a new warning: 
PERFORMANCE WARNING: Overlapping onDeckSearchers=2